# Cannot deploy my application on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise, asset-pipeline

I cant deploy my application on heroku i tried alot but no luck !
and i have tried `bundle update` but also not working

```
Application Error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

in my Gemfile i added `gem 'devise'` and `gem 'cancan'` under `gem 'rails'` and `ruby '1.9.3'` above `gem 'rails'`

application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'devise'


    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

When i do `git push heroku master`, i see the following during pushing

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__1823897648455200442__prepare__4158920102365195865__callbacks'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_2avqf4cxqc1b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
-----> WARNINGS:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
```

after this i type `heroku run rake db:migrate`, i get the following

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.4282
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Devise
/app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

update: i have added  `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to application.rb instead of production.rb

```
git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:nameless-lowlands-8457.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:nameless-lowlands-8457.git (push)
origin  git://github.com/Code-Vortex/Triton.git (fetch)
origin  git://github.com/Code-Vortex/Triton.git (push)
```

But what is posted here not updated in my repo , I consider it as backup.

heroku logs

```
2013-08-13T01:23:51.447646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 13441`
2013-08-13T01:23:56.478911+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-08-13T01:23:56.479632+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-08-13T01:23:56.479271+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-08-13T01:24:02.134733+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.135708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.134384+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.134052+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.134254+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.133824+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
2013-08-13T01:24:02.134534+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.135363+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136273+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.135909+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136004+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.135503+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.134996+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136646+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.134876+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136360+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136841+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136451+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136556+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.137239+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136094+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.136735+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.137143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.137332+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-08-13T01:24:02.137021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-08-13T01:24:05.560278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-13T01:24:05.580273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-13T01:34:05.701049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-13T01:34:11.421800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 13652`
2013-08-13T01:34:14.284915+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-08-13T01:34:14.284557+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-08-13T01:34:14.284661+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.565803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566134+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-08-13T01:34:14.566435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-08-13T01:34:15.747785+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-13T01:34:15.761595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-13T01:44:17.844153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-13T01:44:24.693053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 25419`
2013-08-13T01:44:29.788435+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-08-13T01:44:29.788776+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-08-13T01:44:29.788028+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423252+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423252+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423252+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423252+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423661+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423661+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-08-13T01:44:30.423661+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-08-13T01:44:31.948656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-13T01:44:31.971770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: What a messy question. I don't think posting half your application is actually very helpful.

Comment: Can you run `git remote -v` and post the output here?

Comment: @Nick should i push to github before pushing to heroku ?

Comment: @simonmorley i have posted the files which can cause an error , i have searched here and google for solution and posted what i have tried in a question with my actual problem, so if there is something else someone will tell me , sorry if my question is messy..

Comment: @Nick my question updated

Comment: Can you include a copy of your Gemfile as well?  The failed heroku log led to here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting which indicates that you might not have correctly defined the ruby version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the initialize_on_precompile configuration to false in your application.rb file like so:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Source: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/

Comment: Then check out the other solution in Heroku's troubleshooting section: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting

Comment: i was trying everything the whole day and nothing work i don't know whyyyy >.<

Comment: Tough problem. Try following the solution here: http://blog.genuitytech.com/2012/01/31/heroku-labs-and-user-env-compile/ and tell me how it goes.